# Redirect via .htaccess issue (RewriteRule)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following code in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^test/ test.php [NC,L]
```

When I call `http://example.com/test/`, the browser redirects me to the address: `https://example.com/test.php/`, but then the browser shows me an error. I don't want to redirect to `test.php`.

Comment: `https://example.com/test.php/` - Just to confirm, is there a slash at the end of the redirected URL? What do you want to happen? And what error are you getting?

Comment: i want that all http redirects to https without change the rela url, now it change the test to test.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling `MultiViews` at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

If `MultiViews` is enabled then mod_negotiation is likely rewriting to `test.php` *before* mod_rewrite gets to redirect to HTTPS. So, mod_rewrite then ends up redirecting to `test.php`.

Comment: thank u!!!! i try to find via google the docu, but can't find, but this is the solution! thank you

Comment: You're welcome. The Apache docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html#multiviews